# Calling a function in code behind using the anchor tag is not working

Tags: c#, html, dynamic, hyperlink

I am trying to add a "NEXT" link onto a panel for a quiz by creating an anchor tag dynamically into a label from code behind to show the link to call a function. The plain link:

```
<a href=\"#\" runat=\"server\"onserverclick=\"getTestG6Ques\" style=\"text-decoration: none; color: #000000;\">NEXT</a>
```

works on the aspx page and it is already part of the content. It calls the function and brings up the next question. It's position is not ideal though. When I insert this code into a label from the aspx.cs page, the "NEXT" link is displayed but it doesn't call the function, although the page refreshes. The code needs to be inside the label to be positioned in the right place.

```
testLabel.Text = "<span style=\"margin:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em; display:block;\">" + "<b>Test Quiz Grade 6: " + testTopic + "<span style=\"margin-left:5em;\"><a href=\"#\" runat=\"server\"onserverclick=\"getTestG6Ques\" style=\"text-decoration: none; color: #000000;\">NEXT</a></span>" + "</b><br /><br />" + dataReader["question"].ToString() + "</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it worked. Your only problem is to write this part:

```
runat=\"server\"onserverclick=\ ...
```

You must put a space between them, So your anchor tag will be this:

```
<a href=\"#\" runat=\"server\" onserverclick=\"getTestG6Ques\" style=\"text-decoration: none; color: #000000;\">NEXT</a>
```

And it will call the method. Only one thing: **getTestG6Ques** must be a public or protected void

```
protected void getTestG6Ques(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // To do some thing.
}
```